# How to store cookies received from a request?

Tags: python, flask, request, session-cookies

I have an application where I make a `request` like this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1'}
d = {'db_name': 'a_database', 'username': 'me', 'password': 'apw'}

db_url = "http://123.45.67.89:1234/something/rest/connections"
r = requests.post(db_url, data=json.dumps(d), headers=headers)
```

This will then create a cookie:

```
r.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='removed', value='removed', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='123.45.67.89', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/something', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='connectname', value='alsoremoved', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='123.45.67.89', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/something/rest', path_specified=False, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)]>
```

I can then use `r.cookies` to make additional `requests` where I then specify `cookies=r.cookies`.

In my flask application, I would like to use the `cookie` in several functions, so I thought I would store it in `session`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, session

session['cookies'] = r.cookies
```

so that I can then later use

```
r2 = requests.post(someurl, data=json.dumps(anotherd), headers=headers, cookies=session['cookies'])
```

However, that results in

> Object of type 'RequestsCookieJar' is not JSON serializable

How would I store `r.cookies` so that it is available in all functions in my application but can vary between users?

Comment: Cookies are not in the session. They are in the request. What lead you in the wrong direction is probably the fact that sometimes, a cookie is used for storing a session id, which is then used to retrieve session data (from memory or from data base or wherever)

Comment: @zvone: Ok, so what would I then store in `session` from the `r.cookies` and how do I then create the `cookies=cookies` part in the next `request` based on what I stored in `session`?

Comment: Playing with Session obbjects is muche easier. Cookies management is transparent. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: @glenfant: Thanks for the link. How would I use it in the described context?

Comment: @Cleb : `from requests import Session` ... `client = Session()` ... `r = client.post(db_url, data=json.dumps(d), headers=headers)`. Then continue later to use this `client` object that will handle the cookies for you. Test it in a iPython REPL for more hints.

Comment: @glenfant: But do I then not run into the same issue as with the cookies? I will have to make `client` available in several functions, so I somehow have to make it globally available (but it also has to be threadsafe). How I would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store the `RequestsCookieJar`, no, but if all you want are the names and values of the cookies, you can trivially convert the jar to a dictionary:

```
session['cookies'] = r.cookies.get_dict()
```

The [`RequestsCookieJar.get_dict()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar.get_dict) also supports filtering by domain and path.

For future requests, the `cookies` parameter of `requests.<METHOD>(...)` calls accepts such a dictionary directly.

Comment: Thanks. How would I then make the next request based on `session['cookies']`? So something like `r2 = request(..., cookies=make_cookie(session['cookies']))`. What would the `make_cookie` be?

Comment: @Cleb: `cookies` accepts a dictionary of name-value pairs *directly*, no need to `make_cookie()` anything.

Comment: Do you think it is the best way to store cookies like this? Is there any better way available/are there any potential downsides?

Comment: @Cleb: the domain / path / browser flags info is dropped. But for a backend REST API call that's almost certainly more than fine. You can always filter the cookies by domain or path first when generating the dict if the API were to issue specialist cookies by path or subdomains. I highly doubt it, however.

Comment: One more question: Is this all threadsafe i.e. can several users use that at the same time without interfering each other?

Comment: @Cleb: yes, there is nothing here that's shared between threads.